# matplotlib python3-2 compatibility

Tags: python, matplotlib, compatibility

I have a code, which worked fine for python3, but after I used 3to2 lib and ran the program for python2 it didn't want to save the histogram and saves just an empty canvas instead. The code looks as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plik='wyniki.out'
def hist(plik):
        dane=np.loadtxt(plik)

        n, bins, patches=plt.hist(dane,int(np.sqrt(len(dane))),normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

        # add a 'best fit' line
        (mu, sigma) = norm.fit(dane)
        y = mlab.normpdf( bins, mu, sigma)
        l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)

        plt.xlabel(ur'Rozmiary krwinek [$\mu m$]')
        plt.ylabel(u'Prawdopodobieństwo')
        plt.title(u'Przykładowy histogram rozkładu czerwonych krwinek, $\mu={0:.3f}, \sigma={1:.3f}$'.format(mu,sigma))
        plt.grid(True)

        plt.show()
        plt.savefig('Przykl_histogram.png')

hist(plik)
```

The file ''wyniki.out'' is a [one-column file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2ir4GCgnr9LUGROQ0VNQUpVMmM). I read that one uses a ''six'' library or something like that, to solve matplotlib compatibility problem, but I couldn't find how to use it. The figure is drawn nicely and the problem might be only with a figure saving. Any way to solve this?